# App got freezes when scrolling in the CollectionView

Tags: swift, caching, uicollectionview, kingfisher

In CollectionView I load images and also **FlurryAds**. I need to show the images even when the app is in offline, So initially I download the images using **KingFisher** and stored in the Cache, Showing the Activity Loader until all the images got downloaded.

This is the code I am using to download the images and store it in the cache,

```
 KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl)!, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
                (image, error, url, data) in
                if let _ = image {
 }
}
```

And load the image in collectionView Cell using **KingFisher**.

```
func setImageFromCache(url: String) {
        let url = URL(string: String(format: "%@", url))
        self.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }
```

The problem is when all the images got downloaded in the cache and I navigate to see the images in collection view, all images are shown, but sometimes when I scroll quickly or scroll, then suddenly gets back to the previous screen app got freezes and has to force close the app.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you strong reference `self` in your block, when you scroll so fast, and all call back is not executed yet, once the view controller is dismiss, it got release, therefore the `self` pointer capture inside that block will be a wild pointer. Then the block execute it, crash.

Try to use [weak self] to capture self in that block

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will do that.

Comment: Can you please tell how and where exactly I need to use  [weak self]

Comment: in any closure { [weak self] (paramA) -> String? in ... }